# Apache [negotiation:error] while opening javascript file

Tags: apache-2.4, 500-error, javascript

I have javascript file with name `circle.terminals.cmd.var.js` and apache return 500 error with:

```
[Sun Jun 15 15:00:55.194900 2014] [negotiation:error] [pid 20095] [client 127.0.0.1:50879] AH00681: Syntax error in type map, no ':' in /var/www/projects/jcubic/terminal/test/cirlce/code/js/circles/terminal/commands/circle.terminals.cmd.var.js for header _global_terminal_dictionary.push( "var" ) ;\r\n
```

`_global_terminal_dictionary.push( "var" )` is first line of js file.

it look like it try to execute that file, why is that? How to make apache to return that file and not execute it?

Answer (score 0):

`mod_negotiation` is causing problems!

Try renaming the file to remove the `var`; that should fix it, right?

I'm not quite sure why it would be applying to a `.var.js` file, but there's probably a `AddHandler type-map .var` in the default configuration that your Apache install came with (and, who knows, maybe even a `.var.js`).

Remove `AddHandler type-map` where it appears in your config, and `mod_negotiation` should stop trying to read your javascript as a type map.